# View/download Freeform Pro entries in MS Word format or other readable format

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have an application form on a web page using "free-form pro" add-on. I can download the entries in CSV / xml / json / text formats but I was wondering if it's possible to download it in a Word format or other more readable format?

The form is made up of around 25 questions (many are text box areas) and reviewing the applications in CSV format is not helpful (lots of horizontal scrolling). Ideally, I would like to view each application separately going through the questions and answers vertically.

The only thing I can think of is taking the xml and mapping it on a web page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to download it in a Word format or other more readable format?

For readability, a PDF is your best bet.

We had an EE application that pulled in XML data, which we stored in entries. We then output that on HTML pages using XSLT in PHP, and we generated PDF versions of the reports available on demand.

We accomplished that with a whole bunch of PHP in templates set to allow PHP on output. Of course, that should really all go into a plugin.

We used [PDFLib](http://www.pdflib.com/). There are [other options](http://www.fpdf.org/) if you Google around.

With PDFLib, we were able to:

- Have a PDF template with header and footer
- Plot any content/data into the PDF with PHP
- Draw image graphics on the fly with another library, also used on the HTML pages, and insert those into the PDF

You can set your headers in PHP to force the content type to PDF data or whatnot. Then when the user clicks the download link, they'll be prompted to download the file. There is no file on the server - Your PHP script is generating PDF output - but you need to tell the browser that. There are lots of [resources on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718962/force-file-download-in-php).

If you're determined to do something in Word, I attempted years ago to merge data/content into RTF format by saving an existing doc as RTF and cracking it open. It was messy. Something that allows you to programmatically insert and plot content into a PDF is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a regular ExpressionEngine template and output the information in whatever format you like.
Use the [Freeform entries tag](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/) to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best for readability is to import into Excel from a CSV export.

After exporting to CSV, change the file name to .txt if it isn't using that already. Then go into Excel and select Open from the File menu, navigate to your .txt file and select it. This will start the Excel import wizard. Click through the wizard and select the appropriate options based on the file and when you get to the end you will have all your data in Excel organized with the appropriate columns.